# Samba multi file share

Tags: samba

I have a diretory like 
samba
  | test1
  | test2

and user A,B.

I hope user A can read and write samba directory.
And user B can read samba directory, but only samba/test2 directory can write.

I use the below config, but when I user samba client, It will show three dirctories.
I hope only show samba directory.

How to config the smb.conf.

```
[samba]
comment = Test Share 
read only = no
path = /home/samba
valid users = A,B
write list = A

[test1]
comment = Test Share 
read only = no
path = /home/samba/test1
valid users = A,B
write list = A

[test2]
comment = Test Share 
read only = no
path = /home/samba/test2
valid users = A,B
write list = A,B
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the testx shares:
browseable = no